# Send error message Flutter via Telegram Bot

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, telegram, telegram-bot

I tried using [Catcher](https://pub.dev/packages/catcher#report-catched-exception), here is my code

```
CatcherOptions debugOptions = CatcherOptions(SilentReportMode(), [
    ConsoleHandler(),
    HttpHandler(HttpRequestType.post,
      Uri.parse("https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=-469322015&text="),
      printLogs: true,
    ),
    
  ]);

  Catcher(MyApp(), debugConfig: debugOptions, releaseConfig: releaseOptions);
```

Everything is fine, but I must enter the error message into this parameter `/sendMessage?chat_id=-469322015&text="Here Error Message"`

Please help me how to do that

Comment: So you want a content of a variable to be part of your String? Or what is the problem? If it is about `"` you can just write: `'https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=-469322015&text="Here Error Message"'`

Comment: @julemand101 . thanks for your response. you can see my answer and give the upvote 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by create own ReportMode

```
class SilentReportMode extends ReportMode {
  @override
  void requestAction(Report report, BuildContext context) {
    // no action needed, request is automatically accepted
    print("HEREEEEE ======= ${report.error}");
    try {
      sendError(report);
    } catch (e) {
    }
    super.onActionConfirmed(report);
  }

  Future sendError(Report report) async {
    try {
      Response response = await Dio().post('https://api.telegram.org/bot<TOKEN>/sendMessage?chat_id=-469322015&text=message: $report',
      );

      print("RESPONSE TELEGErammmmm ====== ${response.data}");
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  @override
  List<PlatformType> getSupportedPlatforms() =>
      [PlatformType.Web, PlatformType.Android, PlatformType.iOS];
}
```